# Only postive integers in input field in react

Tags: reactjs, regex

I have a input field for price and quantity and I want to restrict it to have only +ve integers.
I don't want to do any kind of validation like the `type=number` does half the work, but it still doesn't prevent the input from taking any -ve values or like `+, -, e`.
I don't want to use any 3rd party libraries or need to do any kind of validation or show any error, if the person types in the -ve values or anything then these symbols just should be blocked.
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Use the [min attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp), for example:

```
<input type="number" min={0} />
```

Comment: By doing this, I can still pass the negative values manually